# Which part of the ASP.NET WebAPI is responsible for resolving dynamic to JObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have an ApiController with the following method:

```
public void Post(dynamic data)
{
    Type actualType = data.GetType(); // returns JObject
}
```

When I make an AJAX call, sending JSON data to the controller, the actual type of the 'data' parameter is JObject (from the Newtonsoft.Json library). Which part of the WebAPI is responsible for binding the data from this request to JObject? Is it a model binder? If so, which one ? (there are a several built-in, for instance 'MutableObjectModelBinder', 'TypeMatchModelBinder', etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`. ASP.NET Web API default JSON Formatter is JSON.NET. That is why your dynamic object is converted to JObject. You can switch your default formatter to DataContractJsonSerializer though.

Check out [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization).

> JSON Media-Type Formatter
>
> JSON formatting is provided by the JsonMediaTypeFormatter class. By
>   default, JsonMediaTypeFormatter uses the Json.NET library to perform
>   serialization. Json.NET is a third-party open source project.
>
> If you prefer, you can configure the JsonMediaTypeFormatter class to
>   use the DataContractJsonSerializer instead of Json.NET. To do so, set
>   the UseDataContractJsonSerializer property to true:
>
> var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
>   json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;

You can change your JSON formatter configuration from WebApiConfig